# Tabulator - Column formatting incorrect

Tags: tabulator

I have created a tabulator table and it looks great exactly what I want...
[image]

I am then giving the users the ability to save it. I am saving the data, and the column definitions.

When I bring it back I the formatting looks completely incorrect, see below.

[image]

So the columns are there and look correct. The data is there, but clearly, the formatting is wrong. Can anyone suggest what I am missing to ensure the table comes back as expectetd??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have sorted it... if anyone needs it I should have been using table.getColumnLayout(), rather than table.getColumns();